# what are gnome-session and gnome-settings-daemon?

Tags: gnome, session, settings, display-manager

Can someone explain to me exactly what `gnome-session` and `gnome-settings-daemon` do and how they might be useful to me, as someone who doesn't use GNOME or any of its relatives as a DM (i use i3)?

I've only known that one of the two can be used to automatically set media keybindings but am increasingly bothered that I know neither which one sets the keybindings nor what either of them is really for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gnome-session *starts* gnome-settings-daemon.  The latter manages the data used in a session.  The former tells it what to do.

Based on the description, you'll be more interested in the settings daemon than the session manager.

Further reading:

- [Difference between gnome-session and gnome-shell?](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=202687)

  > by default gnome.session starts gnome-shell and gnome-settings-daemon,
- [gnome-settings-daemon-3.20.1](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/systemd/gnome/gnome-settings-daemon.html)

  > The GNOME Settings Daemon is responsible for setting various parameters of a GNOME Session and the applications that run under it.
- [Package: gnome-settings-daemon](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/rpmphp/zoom.php?rpm=gnome-settings-daemon)

  > The daemon sharing settings from GNOME to GTK+/KDE applications
- [gnome-settings-daemon](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/gnome-settings-daemon)

  > This package contains the daemon which is responsible for setting the various parameters of a gnome session and the applications that run under it. it handles the following kinds of settings:
  >
  > - keyboard: layout, accessibility options, shortcuts, media keys
  > - clipboard management
  > - theming: background, icons, gtk+ applications
  > - cleanup of unused files
  > - mouse: cursors, speed, accessibility options
  > - startup of other daemons: screensaver, sound daemon
  >     it also sets various application settings through x resources and freedesktop.org xsettings.
- [gnome-session-3.20.2](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/systemd/gnome/gnome-session.html)